# Are asynchronous RESTful web services possible?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous, jax-rs

Reading [RESTful](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) documentation, it does not seem like it is possible to implement an asynchronous instance, but someone may know better on SO.

What I mean here is I would like to execute service requests asynchronously:

```
@Path("/helloworld", asyncSupported=true)
public class MyHelloWorldService {
    ...
}
```

I know `asyncSupported` is not defined in `@Path`, but I am looking for something similar to `@WebServlet`. Then, I would like to use `AsyncContext` instances (or anything equivalent).

Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use AJAX to call your RESTful method asynchronously?

Comment: @The Because AsyncContext was implemented to solve the excessive thread-per-request issue in Servlet. Using Ajax to call RESTful would not tackle this issue (on the server side). The idea/solution is to queue requests for processing on a limited set of threads (a bit like Nginx).

Comment: You might want to ask on the http://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive list. IIRC Jersey experimented with futures some time ago. Not sure whether that evolved.

Comment: You may want to look something like Apache ServiceMix for inspiration.

Comment: Are you asking whether this is possible in your library, or how to tackle asynchrony in REST interfaces in general?

Comment: @PartlyCloudy If I implement my RESTful service, can I generate and use an AsyncContext for each received request or not? That's what I am wondering...

Comment: So you are asking about a specific Java-based implementation of a RESTful webservice, and not how to design an API and its resources for asynchronous patterns.

Comment: Simply you can not. However the future version of the Restful Web Services for Java (JSR 339) will address these issues. I have also replied too.

Comment: have a look at this. https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RestEasy has some support<sup>1</sup> for it - using a custom annotation called `@Suspend`.

See here:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.1.GA/userguide/html/Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing.html

There is also a framework/library on top of Jersey called Atmosphere however that might be overkill for your usecase as its focus appears to be on long-polling client/server web applications ( e.g. chats - https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere )

[1] The CDI scope for your request will be lost in in the thread that actually executes the logic. See the [RESTEasy-682](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-682) issue for more information. This is a problem that hasn't been solved by any REST frameworks that I know of at this moment<sup>[March 2014]</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

It's apparently possible with [CXF and Jetty Continuations](http://sberyozkin.blogspot.com/2008/12/continuations-in-cxf.html) but that only appears to be possible with Jetty 6; they've been changed in Jetty 7 to something that's in the Servlet 3.0 spec and I don't know if that's supported by CXF. Moreover, Jetty Continuations seem to be a bit of [a messy API, with a lot of manual stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1204355/301832) so I don't know how easy it is to convert the code.

Still, somewhat possible it seems. With a following breeze and when God wills it.

Answer (score 2):

Restful spesification is still at early ages of its life. But this problem should be considered as 2 part. Client and Server.

Client:

For the client side recent changes at last year became mature enough. And recently a non blocking client from based on [Jeanfrancois Arcand](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client) was implemented and pushed to repository. There is an explanation [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/jersey_non_blocking_client).

Server:

For the server side, it is still immature. The adoption of the new servlet specification is quite slow and as a developer I am expecting [JSR 339](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) to address these issues as well. And this is also addressed at the JSR spec clearly with these sentences.

> JAX-RS 1.1 defines a synchronous request response model on the server
>   side. This JSR will specify a simple asynchronous request processing
>   model such that a response can be returned asynchronous to the
>   request. Servlet 3.0 can be leveraged to enable such support but
>   implementations may choose to use other container-specific APIs
>   instead.

However there are other alternatives too. Projects such as Jetty are addressing such kind of problems elegant as in this [example](http://java.dzone.com/news/asynchronous-restful-web-appli). I can only suggest you to consider other alternatives as the community is growing.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can make Asynchoronous RESTful calls using JAX-RS 2.0 API which is part of the recently released Java EE 7.0

http://www.slideshare.net/reza_rahman/jaxrs2?ref=

Answer (score 1):

Check out Pubsubhubbub found [here](https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) for an example of a REST-based asynchronous protocol.  It is based on the Atom Syndication format and is a lot simplier than WS-* pub/sub mechanisms.

Comment: That's a Ruby solution, do you have the Java one?

Comment: When I refer to asynchronous, I mean asynchronous request processing on server side...

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try Spring [Webflux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html) which is async and reactive at the same time. However, this is not a JAX-RS implementation from Java EE.